# React conditional rendering in Array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

I'm trying to figure out conditional rendering in React. I get five categories from API, i just want to print one p tag on basis of categories condition

My Current try :

```
this.state.links.map(link => 
    div className="youtubeLinks">                       
        <p> print category 1</p>
        <p> print category 2</p>
        <p> print category 3</p>
        <p> print category 4</p>
        <p> print category 5</p>
    </div>
```

Want to achieve

```
if(link.category == 1){
<p> print category 1</p>
} 
if(link.category == 2){
<p> print category 2</p>
} 
if(link.category == 3){
<p> print category 3</p>
} 
if(link.category == 4){
<p> print category 4</p>
} 
if(link.category == 5){
<p> print category 5</p>
}
```

Comment: Why you need this? Just use one `p` and change content inside, depends on category

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like this

```
this.state.links.map(link => 
    <div className="youtubeLinks">                       
        {link.category == 1 && <p> print category 1</p>}
        {link.category == 2 && <p> print category 2</p>}
        {link.category == 3 && <p> print category 3</p>}
        {link.category == 4 && <p> print category 4</p>}
        {link.category == 5 && <p> print category 5</p>}
        <img src={link.link} /> // Here is error img
    </div>
)
```

if you want to only print category inside p tag

```
this.state.links.map(link => 
    <div className="youtubeLinks">                       
        <p> print category {link.category}</p>
    </div>
)
```

For img with p tag

```
this.state.links.map(link => 
    <div className="youtubeLinks">                       
        {link.category == 1 && (
          <>
            <p> print category 1</p>
            <img src={link.link} />
          </>
        )}
        {link.category == 2 && (
          <>
            <p> print category 2</p>
            <img src={link.link} />
          </>
        )}
        {link.category == 3 && (
          <>
            <p> print category 3</p>
            <img src={link.link} />
          </>
        )}
        {link.category == 4 && (
          <>
            <p> print category 4</p>
            <img src={link.link} />
          </>
        )}
        {link.category == 5 && (
          <>
            <p> print category 5</p>
            <img src={link.link} />
          </>
        )}
    </div>
)
```

Comment: hello jay i want to print {link.category == 2 && <img src= {link.link} }. So {link.link} show error under curly braces. So how do i get this?

Comment: @WapShivam dont understand exactly please explain more

Comment: In my link object there is a key link which store image src. So how do i render that image

Comment: @WapShivam i still dont understand but i have added img tag please check answer you dont need to check link.category == 2

Answer (score 0):

You are going good but need a little modification

```
<div className="youtube-links">
 {this.state.links.map(link => (<p>Print category {link.category}</p>))}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say that you array consists of just text links `['link1', 'link2', 'link3]'` and you want to map them out and present them in that p. the link part of your map represents one of the items in you array. I fixed it below.

```
//link represents one item. So when you then say return
```

link it will print each items in the array out individually.

```
 <div className="youtubeLinks">                       
    {this.state.links.map(link => {
        return <p> print category {link}</p>
    })}
 </div>
```